# How do I run previous iOS versions on my simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

I'm well aware that it's possible to go to `hardware->device->manage devices`, then click the plus button and add a new simulator with an old `iOS` version. But the problem is that the earliest version I can pick (download) is `iOS 10`. Is there a way to get ahold of `iOS 8`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download old Xcode Versions including older simulator versions here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: Ah, that's a good idea if it's not possible to get older iOS versions on my current Xcode. Thanks!